# size of node with shape=circle

Tags: size, graphviz, dot, geometry, shapes

i'm trying to set the size of the nodes this way:

```
controller[shape=circle,width=.5,label="Controller",style=filled,fillcolor="#8EC13A"];
```

But all three nodes are with different size. How can i set fixed size?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From the DOT Guide http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf on page 4 it says the following:

> When drawn, a
>   node’s actual size is the greater of the requested size and the area needed for its text
>   label, unless *fixedsize=true*, in which case the width and height values
>   are enforced.

Thus you simply need to add *fixedsize=true* to your code